What are these DMARC failures about?
I've been toying with dmarc off and on for the last couple of months.  Currently I have no policy set. I am using URIReports for report collection and analysis. Most of the results are good. We use Google for interpersonal email, Mailchimp for mass email, and Amazon SES for transactional things. But there are a LOT of failures involving various Microsoft mail senders, and we don't use MS at all.  We are a Mac/Linux shop, and our servers do not even have a mail server running on them.  Here is a screen shot of the failures in URIReports.

Almost all of the failures involve academic institutions, which sort of makes sense since most of our clients are academic. Is one of our legitimate affiliates sending email to these recipients "from" our domain thinking that it's OK to do so?  Is this spam/phishing targeting our clients (that does happen!)? Is this a peculiarity of the MS ecosystem that generates failures? We do have a LOT of recipients who give us their institutional email address (.edu accounts) that then forward to personal accounts automatically.
I have tried getting failure/forensic reports but haven't ever received even one. I have come to understand they aren't widely supported for privacy reasons.
Thanks

Your recipients may have setup e-mail forwarding , which can break sender authentication schemes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_Received_Chain are examples of how that can potentially be fixed

Thanks.  The SRS seems to be something an intermediate server implements?  If that's the case, there's nothing I can do about it?  The ARC seems to me to be the more actionable approach, and I checked the headers for mail sent via Mailchimp (the more likely server based on recipient domain and volume) and all those headers are there.  The Results header shows "pass" for SPF, DKIM and DMARC.
